# Detect overlapping between two squares/rectangles JAVA

Tags: java, geometry, logic, overlap

I don't know how to complete this. I'm learning by myself and I found this exercise where you have a class for a rectangle like this:

```
public class Rectangulo {

private int x, y, width, heigth;

public Rectangulo(int x, int y, int width, int heigth){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.heigth = heigth;
}

public boolean isOverlaping(Rectangulo r1, Rectangulo r2){

}
```

And I have to complete the method so it returns true if the 2 rectangles are overlapping / colliding or false if they aren't. Can you give me any guide to help me think this problem, or tips?

I don't have to use the intersects method.

Thanks!

Comment: I made a drawing and I don't know what the x and y values represent. I mean, a rectangle is made by 4 points with x and y each one. I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the method, you're provided with two rectangle objects as arguments, r1 & r2. Each instance has its specific value for x,y, width and height. You can use these values to determine whether the two rectangles collide or overlap

For your specific doubt, you might want to read the [javadoc for Rectangle.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html). This will help you understand how a rectangle is created in Java

Comment: But, I only have 1 point x and 1 point y for each rectangle. How do I know which corner these points belong to?

Comment: Did you read the link? It specifically says, "A Rectangle specifies an area in a coordinate space that is enclosed by the Rectangle object's upper-left point (x,y) in the coordinate space, its width, and its height.". Do spend some time to read it :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) In case this helps, please also consider accepting the answer!

Comment: Sure bro, I just have to wait 5 minutes, but I will do it :)